# Time-dependent market-clearing equilibrium price

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, equilibrium-price

I'm working my way through Chiang and Wainwright's *Fundamental Methods of Mathematical Economics* (4th ed) while holed up at home. On p. 532, in exercise 16.4 2. (b), the authors ask you to find the intertemporal equilibrium price and the market-clearing equilibrium price in the following model:

$$\begin{align}
Q_d & = \alpha - \beta P + m P' + n P'' \\
Q_s & = -\gamma + \delta P \\
P' & = j(Q_d - Q_s)
\end{align}$$

where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta > 0$, and $n \ne 0$. Reducing this to a single second-order differential equation yields

$$P'' + \frac{ mj - 1 }{ n } P' - \frac{ \beta + \delta }{ n } P = -\frac{ \alpha + \gamma }{ n }$$

from which the *intertemporal* equilibrium price

$$\bar P = \frac{ \alpha + \gamma }{ \beta + \delta }$$

can immediately be inferred. Now, for the *market-clearing* equilibrium price, my approach was to set $Q_s = Q_d$ and solve for $P$, observing that for $Q_s = Q_d$, $P' = 0$ by the third model equation; this yields

$$P^*(t) = \frac{ \alpha + \gamma + n P''(t) }{ \beta + \delta }$$

However, looking at the solution for this exercise, I'm finding that the market-clearing equilibrium price is *also* supposed to be

$$P^* = \frac{ \alpha + \gamma }{ \beta + \delta }$$

according to the authors. This would seem to require that $P''(t) = 0$ when the market is cleared, and I cannot see how this must necessarily follow from the model equations.

Plugging my solution into the model equations indicates that at the price $P^*(t)$, the market is indeed cleared, though if $P''(t) \ne 0$, this is merely a coincidence. That said, surely the authors are correct, and the error is on my part.

Unfortunately I cannot see *where* I went wrong. I'd appreciate any help, pointers or tips. Thank you, and stay safe!